# add Single Sign-On to a python chatbot (Microsoft Bot Framework ) integrated with Microsoft Teams

Tags: python, azure, botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I want to know how to add the SSO to an  existing chatbot implemented using python on the Microsoft bot framework
if there is any sample available because the samples on the Microsoft docs is all using the C# language not python

Answer (score 1):

A quick web search reveals that there is a whole host of [Python samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python) in the official [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) repository.

Comment: thank you, but i want like these samples in the following link but in python language https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-sso           if you have any samples on the SSO using python please send me the exact link

Comment: @hamzahjazi98

You asked for Microsoft Bot Framework samples, not Teams App samples. If you've checked the official repositories and there are no Python samples, then there are no official Python samples available. If you want a *bot* specifically, consider which framework you want to use.

Comment: yes I want a bot specifically for Microsoft teams using python language, do you have any samples or example on how to add the SSO to the bot?

Comment: The standard pattern to build a bot would be to use the Microsoft Bot Framework, as I linked in my initial answer. You should [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to get a better understanding.